# Интересные учебники по алгоритмам

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Всем привет!

Очень хочется найти такой учебник по алгоритмам, который бы не погружал медленно в сон и не нагонял бы тоску от избытка сложной математической теории. Такой учебник, чтобы суть изложенных в ней алгоритмов можно было понять, возможно, лишь поверхностно. Существуют ли подобные книги? Предпочтителен был бы формат, схожий с тем, которого придерживаются в HeadFirst.

Спасибо!

Comment: М.б. "Искусство программирования" Кнута, если читать "по диагонали"?

Answer (score 0):

- Алгоритмы: "Дж.Макконнел Основы Современных Алгоритмов"
- Немножко математики: "Дискретная математика для программистов, Хаггарти Р."

Answer (score 0):

А пробовал "Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ - Томас Кормен" ???